# capturing video source on html5 video play event

Tags: javascript, html, video

My goal is to get the `src` of the video playing, when the video is played.

I currently have the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
vid.addEventListener('play', function() {
  console.log('video source:',this.src);
}, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So my first problem is that `this.src` doesn't work; it outputs an empty string. I assume this is because the `src` isn't actually part of the `video` tag, but is in the `source` child tag.

I then tried to add into my function the following:

```
for (var p in this) {
  console.log(p, this[p]);
}
```

I did this to see if I could find any properties referencing it.. but I don't see anything that directly references it?  So is the only way to get the source really to grab the child `source` nodes?  If so... then...

My 2nd question, how would I determine which `src` attribute is actually being used to play the video? IOW if `video.mp4` was actually used to play the video, I want to know that value, but if `video.ogg` was actually used to play the video, I want to know that value instead.

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
var vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

vid.addEventListener('play', function() {
    console.log('video source:',this.currentSrc);
}, false);
```

Comment: i went back and looked at the stuff that output from my loop and sure enough it was there..i'm blind!  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [media elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) have a `currentSrc` property to get the chosen media file.

Answer (score 0):

> The HTML5 video element already has events, so there is no need to add a listener. This is how I would do it.

```
var myVid = document.getElementById('videoId');    
if(myVid != null)//if possibility of no video loaded in DOM
{
    myVid.onplay = function () {
        console.log('video source: ' + myVid.currentSrc);
    };
}
```